# SQL - How to turn the rows of a record into columns?

Tags: sql, pivot

i need some help here!!

I have a "users" table within my platform. In this table I have information like:

```
id = is the user ID
created_at = is the date that the user created an agreement within the platform
agent = is responsible for serving the user
```

This information is in the following format:

```
id | created_at | deal_id | agent (columns of the table)
 1 | 2020-08-01 |       1 | 123456
 1 | 2020-09-01 |       2 | 123456
 1 | 2020-09-10 |       3 | 345676
 1 | 2020-10-29 |       4 | 456677
```

I would like to bring this data as follows:

```
 id | created_at1 | created_at2 | created_at3 | created_at4 | agent1 | agent2 | agent3 | agent4
  1 | 2020-08-01  | 2020-09-01  | 2020-09-10  | 2020-10-29  | 123456 | 123456 | 345676 | 456677
```

Is it possible?
I tried to do it with minimum and maximum, but it would only return me two situations.
Remembering that I gave an example of a user, I wanted it to return to all ID's.

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Ideally, in SQL, don't. This is really a task for your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select t.id,
       Max(case when deal_id = 1 then created_at end) as created_at1,
       Max(case when deal_id = 2 then created_at end) as created_at2,
       Max(case when deal_id = 3 then created_at end) as created_at3,
       Max(case when deal_id = 4 then created_at end) as created_at4,
       Max(case when deal_id = 1 then agent end) as agent1,
       Max(case when deal_id = 2 then agent end) as agent2,
       Max(case when deal_id = 3 then agent end) as agent3,
       Max(case when deal_id = 4 then agent end) as agent4
  From your_table t
 Group by id
```

Comment: I think you should treat the case more generally. Like for example, in case there are 3 records, or 5 records etc. Something like that.